# Filter post's category options with hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

On the post edit page I have a category selection box. I would like to filter the displayed categories. How can I do this in PHP? I've tried finding the source of this box in the wordpress-src directory, but haven't had any luck. Can I hook into this and filter what's displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question answered here on the WordPress Stack Exchange:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99034/how-i-can-hide-some-category-from-author-admin-panel

```
/*
 * Hide Specified Categories (by ID) from authors
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion' );

function wpse_55202_do_terms_exclusion() {
    //Where is the string 'author' you need to replace it with your users' role
    if( current_user_can('author') )
        add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_55202_list_terms_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
    // edit 3 with your category's ID
    return $exclusions . " AND ( t.term_id <> 3 ) ";
}
```

Tweak the answer from there to filter out any tag IDs you want hidden, you can also filter for specific user roles or remove that piece.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that you can use which already achieve this type of functionality.

See [Taxonomy Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-filter/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to find a way to do this using just PHP. I'm searching through that plugin's source code right now though for answers